# Spring rest post service sending null values as variable

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, null

I am new to Spring MVC and I am exposing REST services. My `GET` services are working fine but the `POST` call from Postman is sending empty `null` values as fields.

Below is a sample REST service using various forms of `POST` annotations. I'm stuck on this for the past 3 days. Please help.

```
package com.cgi.ehr.rest;

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import com.cgi.ehr.services.dao.UserDetailsDAO;
import com.cgi.test.dto.InputDto;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/bookmarks")
public class CheckingService {

    @EJB
    UserDetailsDAO userDetailsDAO;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/bookmark", method = RequestMethod.GET)

    public InputDto testM() {

        return userDetailsDAO.testMethod();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/testM2", method = RequestMethod.GET,headers="Accept=*/*",  produces="application/json")
    //@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public InputDto testM2() {
        InputDto d = new InputDto("1","2");
        return d;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/bookmarkPost", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    //@ResponseBody
    public InputDto testPost(InputDto inputDto) {
        String age = inputDto.getTestAge();
        String name = inputDto.getTestname();
        InputDto dto = new InputDto();
        dto.setTestAge(age + "gotback");
        dto.setTestname(inputDto.getTestname() + "gotback");

        return dto;
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/bookmarkPost1", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public InputDto testPost1(InputDto inputDto) {
        String age = inputDto.getTestAge();
        String name = inputDto.getTestname();
        InputDto dto = new InputDto();
        dto.setTestAge(age + "gotback");
        dto.setTestname(inputDto.getTestname() + "gotback");

        return dto;
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/person", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=application/xml, application/json")
    public @ResponseBody InputDto addPerson(@RequestBody InputDto inputDto) {
        return inputDto;
    }

}
`

    package com.cgi.test.dto;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class InputDto implements Serializable{


    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String testname;
    private String testAge;
    public String getTestname() {
        return testname;
    }
    public void setTestname(String testname) {
        this.testname = testname;
    }
    public String getTestAge() {
        return testAge;
    }
    public void setTestAge(String testAge) {
        this.testAge = testAge;
    }
    public InputDto() {
        super();
    }
    public InputDto(String testname, String testAge) {

        this.testname = testname;
        this.testAge = testAge;
    }


}
```

[image]

Comment: input json :     {
  "testname": "myname",
  "testAge": "myage"
}

Comment: output json : {
  "testname": "nullgotback",
  "testAge": "nullgotback"
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your testPost method should look like below. Now you can use same request using Postman.

```
          @RequestMapping(value = "/bookmarkPost", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
          public @ResponseBody InputDto testPost(@RequestBody InputDto inputDto) {
               String age = inputDto.getTestAge();
               String name = inputDto.getTestname();
               InputDto dto = new InputDto();
               dto.setTestAge(age + "gotback");
               dto.setTestname(name + "gotback");
               return dto;
    }
```

Comment: Tried this but now i get an error running on postman "The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect." ...

Comment: What request are you sending? I tested your code and  it is  working fine for me with request you have given above. Response I am getting is {
  "testname": "mynamegotback",
  "testAge": "myagegotback"
}

Comment: Could you please send me your entire service and to file? which headers are you using if any? ... my request is below:

Comment: {
  "testname": "myname",
  "testAge": "myage"
}

Comment: I am using same InputDto what you have posted with the code I have provided. Header contains Content-Type=application/json. Can you please post your modified controller code so I can have a look?

Comment: @RequestMapping(value = "/bookmarkPostt", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody InputDto teestPost(@RequestBody InputDto inputDto) {
         String age = inputDto.getTestAge();
         String name = inputDto.getTestname();
         InputDto dto = new InputDto();
         dto.setTestAge(age + "gotback");
         dto.setTestname(name + "gotback");
         return dto;
}

Comment: Your code looks ok. I can only suggest you to remove other methods from that controller and keep only this method . Then clean build your project and test it.

Comment: Sorry @abaghel ...code was working all along , i was making a very silly mistake while submitting post data in postman (i chose the wrong tab and did not send it under the "body" ) ... i wasted 3 days on this !!!!..anyways thanks again

Answer (score 0):

In your `InputDto` class your setters correctly set the instance variable `this.testXxx`

```
public void setTestname(String testname) {
    this.testname = testname;
}
```

Your getters, however, do not return this instance variable. Note your missing `this.` The following should fix your current problem, then, applied to both getters.

```
public String getTestAge() {
    return this.testAge;
}
```

Comment: @XmlRootElement
public class InputDto implements Serializable{
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 private String testname;
 private String testAge;
 
 public String getTestname() {
  return this.testname;
 }
 public void setTestname(String testname) {
  this.testname = testname;
 }
 public String getTestAge() {
  return this.testAge;
 }
 public void setTestAge(String testAge) {
  this.testAge = testAge;
 }
 public InputDto() {
  super();
 }
 public InputDto(String testname, String testAge) {
  
  this.testname = testname;
  this.testAge = testAge;
 }

Answer (score 0):

Sorry Guys...code was working all along , i was making a very silly mistake while submitting post data in postman (i chooses the wrong tab and did not send it under the "body" ) ... i wasted 3 days on this !!!!..anyways thanks again @abaghel